# Автоматическое добавление в проект пакета NuGet (VSIX)

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-extensions

Товарищи!

Встал перед такой проблемой:

Написал расширение для `Visual Studio`, которое работает в паре с библиотекой, которая также написана мной

Хотелось бы иметь возможность автоматически добавлять мою библиотеку в открываемые проекты (с разрешения конечного пользователя, понятное дело. Опустим это)

В какую сторону смотреть в поисках решения данной задачи?

---

*Доп. информация:*

- Библиотека скомпилирована отдельно для `.NET Framework` и `.NET Core`
  (в `.NET Standart` запихнуть не вышло), что немного усложняет задачу
- Библиотека будет доступна на `NuGet`
- Расширение написано для `Visual Studio 2017` (протестировано там же)
- Библиотеку я также упаковываю и внутрь `VSIX`

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен, какие соображения мешают изначально положить библиотеку вместе с плагином к студии в vsix? Зачем его тянуть отдельно? А по сути, это делается зависимостью в target в nuget, как обстоят дела в vsix не в курсе, но уверен что там тоже можно описать зависимости.

Comment: @NewView: библиотека подключается к .NET-проекту пользователя (на C#, VB или F#), а не к самому расширению

Comment: Дык.. пусть ваш плагин при включении в проекте добавляет target зависимость в виде этого пакета. Имеется в виду файл vproj. Nuget то тоже самое делает, по сути, добавляет зависимость в проект, добавляя ее к целям сборки. Посмотрите примеры target файлов для nuget.

Comment: @NewView: вот у меня и отсутствует понимание, как это правильно сделать (в случае с несколькими библиотеками) хД

Comment: Посмотрите [например тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788961/setting-file-properties-with-nuget-using-targets-file), как отправная точка.

Comment: @NewView: спасибо! Кажется, я придумал, как решить задачу

Comment: Не забудьте поделиться с общественностью решением :)

Comment: @NewView: конечно)

Comment: Почему не устанавливать по аналогии с обычным способом, т.е когда вручную через `NuGet Package Manager` устанавливают что-то? С учетом того, что она доступна через nuget.org.

Comment: @UserName: 0) Как бы запустить этот процесс автоматически? 1) А если у пользователя нет доступа к сети?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, по вопросу с индексом `0` дал ответ. Вопрос с индексом `1` не кажется мне существенным, хотя я не знаю вашей специфики.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, не знаю, удовлетворит ли решение, но тем не менее. Если что-то описано не очень понятно дайте знать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вопрос того, как именно будет даваться разрешение на установку вашей
>   библиотки будет опущен.

---

Можно воспользоваться функционалом `MSBuild`. Необходимо установить следующие библиотеки:

- Microsoft.Build

> This package contains the Microsoft.Build assembly which is used to
>   create, edit, and evaluate MSBuild projects.

- Microsoft.Build.Framework

> This package contains the Microsoft.Build.Framework assembly which is
>   a common assembly used by other MSBuild assemblies.

---

После установки библиотек, можно получить доступ к структуре проекта следующим образом:

```
public Project GetLoadedProject(string project)
{
    return ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.LoadProject(project);
}
```

---

После того, как структура получена, можно добавить новый элемент, который представляет собой ссылку на библиотеку, а именно элемент `PackageReference` группы `ItemGroup`:

```
public void AddPackage(Project project, string packageIdentity, string packageVersion)
{
    project.AddItemFast("PackageReference", packageIdentity, new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Version", packageVersion }
    });

    project.Save();
}
```

---

Для получения проектов решения можно воспользоваться [Env.DTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017):

```
public IEnumerable<EnvDTE.Project> GetSolutionProject(EnvDTE.DTE dte)
{
    List<EnvDTE.Project> projects = new
    List<EnvDTE.Project>();

    foreach (EnvDTE.Project project in dte.Solution.Projects)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(project.FileName))
            continue;

        projects.Add(project);
    }

    return projects;
}
```

После чего можно передавать `FullPath` проектов в метод [LoadProject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectcollection.loadproject?view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_Build_Evaluation_ProjectCollection_LoadProject_System_String_) как показано выше.

---

**UPD**. Есть еще [NuGet API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/nuget-api-in-visual-studio) доступный из `VisualStudio`. В данном случае следует обратить внимание на интерфейс [IVsPackageInstaller](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/nuget-api-in-visual-studio#ivspackageinstaller-interface), который определяет метод для установки пакетов. Его методы поразумевают использование [EnvDTE.Project](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.project?view=visualstudiosdk-2017), который можно получить методом показанном выше.

---

[Project](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project?view=netframework-4.7.2) | [ProjectCollection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectcollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) | [AddItemFast](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.additemfast?view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_Build_Evaluation_Project_AddItemFast_System_String_System_String_) | [Env.DTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) | [_DTE.Solution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.solution?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) | [EnvDTE.Project](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.project?view=visualstudiosdk-2017).

Comment: Ух, спасибо большое) Буду сегодня ночью пробовать хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, получилось?

Comment: в процессе) Извините, пожалуйста, тут дела опять навалились. Как только все протестирую, отмечу ответом) В самом NuGet интерфейсе есть возможность установки из кастомного источника, коим может являться и папка на локальном компьютере. Так что решение я сейчас вижу таковым: упаковать мою библиотеку в nupkg, при открытии решения с помощью NuGet API «устанавливать» этот самый пакет из директории с расширением. Как-то так

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, я так понимаю речь про global packages folder. А туда пакет как попадет?

Comment: нет, не про него) В `nuget.exe` можно так: `nuget install MyPackage -Source C:\MyPackages`. А так как предложенный Вами `Nuget API` работает на основе всего этого дела, то с его помощью, думаю, тоже можно провернуть что-то такое

Comment: Простите, пожалуйста, что я так долго... Перед Новым годом как всегда завал работы и времени на свои проектики совсем мало остаётся ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Когда будет время, напишу итоговый вариант