# Как автоматически изменить проект при добавлении его в solution (Visual Studio)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

Коллеги, доброго дня!

Есть здоровый солюшен (.sln) в который постоянно добавляются новые проекты (.csproj).
Необходимо следить за их настройками и автоматически корректировать.

В нашем случае это параметры анализа кода, которые необходимо переопределить, добавив соответствующие параметры в базовую секцию, и убрать лишние из платформо-зависимых.

Как это сделать?

[Варианты с экстеншенами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/917421/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-nuget-vsix) для студии рассматриваются в последнюю очередь.

Comment: Что такое `базовая секция`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `Directory.Build.prop`, который будет автоматически импортирован в проекты:

> Directory.Build.props is imported very early in
>   Microsoft.Common.props, and properties defined later are unavailable
>   to it. So, avoid referring to properties that are not yet defined (and
>   will evaluate to empty).

а так же `Directory.Build.targets`:

> Directory.Build.targets is imported from Microsoft.Common.targets
>   after importing .targets files from NuGet packages. So, it can
>   override properties and targets defined in most of the build logic,
>   but sometimes you may need to customize the project file after the
>   final import.

---

Это относится к процессу сборки. Если требуется изменение файлов, то без расширений не обойтись, можно кастомный шаблон проекта реализовать.

---

[Customize your build](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017#directorybuildprops-example)